# AsyncTasck and Thread

Tags: java, android

I'm very confused working with `AsyncTask` and `Thread`.I know that there is no need to create a new `Thread` in `AsyncTask`, but I have to.In `AsyncTask` I get some data from server and need to get photo from another server. So I create `request` to social network's DB and get it. The `request` executes in the new Thread. **Here is the problem:** `AsyncTask` execute only half of `requests` and only sometimes all of them. 11 requests and executes only 7 of them

The `AcynTask`:

```
  public DB_read_all(Context _context){
    context = _context;
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    // getting JSON string from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_read_all, "GET", params);

    // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
    if(json!=null){
        //Log.e("Users_all: ", json.toString());
        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                users = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USERS);
                Log.e("Succes getting users, users amount",                 String.valueOf(users.length()));

                for (int i = 0; i < users.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject c = users.getJSONObject(i);
                    id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    first_name = c.getString(TAG_FIRST_NAME);
                    ListOfFName.add(first_name);

                    last_name = c.getString(TAG_LAST_NAME);  
                    ListOfLName.add(last_name);

                    vk_id = c.getString(TAG_VK_ID);
                    ListOfVkId.add(vk_id);

                    points= c.getString(TAG_POINTS);
                    ListOfPoints.add(points);
                }
            } else {
                  Log.e("DB_read_all","Db Error!");
            }
        } catch (JSONException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e){

            Logger logger = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "an exception was thrown while converting", e);
            Log.e("DB_read_all","Db Error!");
        }
    } else{
        Log.e("DB_read_all","JSON ERROR");
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<ListOfFName.size();i++){
        setUserPhotoUrl(ListOfFName.get(i), ListOfLName.get(i), ListOfVkId.get(i), ListOfPoints.get(i));
    }
    return null;
}
```

Method with request in the new Thread:

```
private void setUserPhotoUrl(final String _first_name,
                             final String _last_name,final String _vk_id,final String _points){
    VKRequest request = VKApi.users().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.USER_ID, _vk_id,
            VKApiConst.FIELDS, "photo_100"));

    request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(final VKResponse response) {
            super.onComplete(response);
            //Log.e("second", String.valueOf(I));
            //Log.e("second", String.valueOf(_first_name));
                    VKList<VKApiUser> User = (VKList<VKApiUser>) response.parsedModel;
                    if(User.get(0).photo_100!=null)
                    photo_url = User.get(0).photo_100;

                    Bitmap photoBm = null;

                    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                    if(photo_url !=null){
                        try {
                            photoBm = Internet.convertUrlToImage(photo_url);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Logger logger = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();
                            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "an exception was thrown while converting", e);
                        }
                    }
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    if(photoBm!= null)
                        photoBm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);

                    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
                    String encodedPhoto = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

            editor.putString("UserFirstName" + String.valueOf(I), _first_name);
            editor.putString("UserLastName" + String.valueOf(I), _last_name);
            editor.putString("UserVkId" + String.valueOf(I), _vk_id);
            editor.putString("UserPoints" + String.valueOf(I), _points);
            editor.putString("UserPhoto"+String.valueOf(I),encodedPhoto);
            editor.apply();

            if(I == users.length() - 1){
                Log.e("DB_read_all","Success");
            }
            Log.e("second",String.valueOf(I));
            I++;
        }
```

Comment: then transfer all your code to the Thread and forget async task, and let that thread do the double work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thread/Runable runs in separate thread other than main gui thread, while Async is running on both main and worker thread, `onPreExecute`/`onPostExecute` runs in main thread while `doInBackground` runs in separate thread says worker thread, while for your problem do not create another thread inside `doInBackground` because itself it is thread, so why you are creating another thread to load/post data from/to another server, you can do as much as u can in your `doInBackground`, yes if you want to execute parallel execution use threadpool executor to start your `asynctask`. Yes you can do it with simple threads but they runs on a separate thread so you can not directly control these threads if you are not using handlers etc.
I highly suggest you use async tasks over threads/runnable

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java

check out @212 in above source. You DONT WANT the default executor which will result in single threads. Note that you can control POOL Size, thread priority fields used by this class.

When you get a response from the request on Domain#1 and are ready to do GET from domain #2  i think you want to go back to a pool running in the same LOOPER as was used in req. -> domain #1 and run the 2nd async Task by submitting a request to the 2nd domain in a Diff asyncTask.

with your questions on AsyncTask, you may benefit from looking thru what its actually doing. I believe its just posting a Runnable to a queue and handling the result.